# configurable product price does not change auto after select option from dropdown in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Magento configurable product does not change price as I select options from dropdown. I am using a custom theme.

for example : Parent Product has two sizes Size 1 and Size 2. 
Size 1 is of $100,
Size 2 is of $200

As I select Size 2 the price on product detail page should changed to $200

What are the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add base price to the configurable product.

Under the associated tab where the list of simple product selected for the configurable product.

under the "Super product attributes configuration" specify the price difference in front of each simple product

for ex:  Configurable product price is $20 and attributes are REd, Yellow

Product with Red attribute is of $22
Product with yellow attribute is of $24

So specify 2 for red attribute product and 4 for yellow attribute product